# following guava development of new features

Tags: java, guava

Is there a way to follow early API drafts (for instance once accepted in the issue tracker, the drafts, iterations and internal discussions why something is not done this way but that way...)? I suppose there's a lot to learn from these discussions.

Answer (score 4):

From [the project page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

> ## How to communicate with us (and each other)
>
> To stay informed and get "tip of the week"-style posts, follow [+Google Guava](https://plus.google.com/118010414872916542489) on Google+.
>
> To just stay informed, period, about important news that every Guava user needs to know, subscribe to [guava-announce](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-announce). It is very low-traffic.
>
> To report a defect or request a feature, click the Issues tab above and enter a new issue.
>
> To get help on a specific question or problem, post a question to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=java+guava) with the tag "guava". We monitor these questions using [this RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=guava&sort=newest).)
>
> Keep an eye on project updates using any of these [Project Feeds](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/feeds). (The "Updates" feed is an aggregation of all the others.) You can view our code changes as they happen, and comment on them using the code-review tool.
>
> We have a read-only [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-issues) consisting of email notifications of issue tracker activity, which can be easier to follow in a threaded manner than the project feed.
>
> For general discussion that doesn't fit neatly into any of these categories, join our discussion group [guava-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss).

Most likely, you want the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-issues), the ATOM feed for [issue updates](https://code.google.com/feeds/p/guava-libraries/issueupdates/basic), or the [guava-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss) group.

Comment: Hm I think guava-discuss is maybe the closest. But I suppose most early drafts are internally discussed. For instance I'm particularly interested in (and not just the "resulting" API / implementation but also maybe some iterations on why the API is like it is (once it's released)): http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Package%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=174

Comment: Yep, this discussion is basically all internal.

Comment: @Johannes You could always send a message on the mailing list asking to make that sort of discussion more open. It may not be likely but it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but it's really difficult to hit on a process that keeps the right people in the loop on the right things and isn't completely unmanageable. We don't wish to shut out external users from our design discussions, but we don't know how it fits naturally into the workflow at this point.

Comment: Thanks, as someone who just graduated from university it's at least _very_ inspiring how the things in Guava are done :-) I doubt I could give any useful input, it's just that I already learned a lot while reading some source code, probably in the same extend as reading Effective Java (and listening to some talks) from Josh Bloch some years ago ;-) So I just thought I'd ask, because the decisions which lead to for instance the APIs are for sure equally interesting.